# Why my login code is not working?

Tags: c#, sql

I am making a user login program, My code is as follow:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string b = Convert.ToString(UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem);
        SqlConnection DataFind = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=PAYROLL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM;Integrated security=true;");
        DataFind.Open();

        SqlCommand dmd;
        dmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LoginDetail where( (UserName=' " + b + "') AND (Password='" + Password.Text + "' ))", DataFind);
        dmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(dmd.ExecuteScalar());

        DataFind.Close();
        SelectedRowNo.Text = count.ToString();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Form1 s = new Form1();
            s.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry You are not an authirized user");
        }
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("UserName or Password not valid"); }
}
```

It is not giving me any output. It says that no record found, although the record exist in sql database.I am unable to understand why my program is not working.

Comment: You have a typo. There is a space before the variable _b_ that contains the username _where( (UserName=' " + b + "')_

Comment: ... which is why you should be using parameters.

Comment: Before you do anything else read about Sql injection and parameterized queries. After that, read about password hashing or watch [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)

Comment: Also, you are using a combo box to let the user choose the username - this is giving up half the security. What's stoping someone from brut forcing the password after you've given them all your user names?

Comment: I'm removing my close vote (simple typo reason) because I think the answer is important. I wonder if changing the title to "How can I make my login code work right" or something like that might reinforce that the problem is not simply the extra space.

Answer (score 8):

You have one extra spaces - before the username. Remove it and it should work.

Keep in mind, though, that you're doing more or less everything wrong here. You're vulnerable to SQL Injection (think what happens when someone gives you the password `ab')); DROP TABLE Users; --`), and you're storing the clear password in the database, so anybody who can access your data can get all your user passwords. And since you're open to SQL injection, anybody can get your data.

https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: the extra space after the password shouldn't actually hurt anything, since it's outside of the ' characters

Comment: Right! Corrected my answer.

Comment: You might add a short bit about the importance of hashing passwords before storing them.

Comment: I did, last sentence before the XKCD link.